# Async TCP Server Programming with Python And Postgresql

Tags: python, tcp, network-programming, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I have some embedded C programming experience but new with Python.

I designed a sensor circuit. The circuit will connect a TCP server via GPRS and will send some sensor data. I will have 1000-2000 device and those ones will stay connected to TCP server 7/24 and each of them will send approximately 100-150 byte data to TCP server in every 1 minute. The TCP server will parse( function didn't applied in the code below ) those data and will write to a Postgresql database table.

I should write a TCP server which can scale that traffic. I will have 1000-2000 device, because of this i don't want to use thread approach for my TCP server. So i decided to write with async approach.

I did some research for that and i tried to make the code below. But i don't know how to test this code without having 1000 device on the site and don't know this works asynchronously, without blocking the cpu.

If this works as expected( asynchronously ) can this approach scale 1000-2000 device when every device will send 100-150 byte data in every 1 minute with a 1 core, 2GB ram virtual private server?

And basically i can send a setting to the devices, about which device should send its data in which second. By doing this, in each second i will have approximately 40 data structure ( lets say i have 2000 device every minute i will have 2000 data structure 2000/60=33.3 approx. 40 data structure per sec )

Thanks for your answer and best regards.

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg
#async olup olmadığı bilinmiyor.

class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport   

        
    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))
        
        database_handle()
        
        print('Send: {!r}'.format(message))
        self.transport.write(data)

        print('Close the client socket')
        self.transport.close()

    def connection_lost(self, transport):
        peername = self.transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('{} is disconnected from server'.format(peername))
        return super().connection_lost(transport)

async def database_handle(data):
    async with poolsql.acquire() as connection:
    # Open a transaction.
        async with connection.transaction():
        # Run the query passing the request argument.
            result = await connection.execute('''INSERT INTO deneme(data) VALUES($1)''',data)
            print(result)
    
async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    global poolsql
    poolsql=await asyncpg.create_pool('postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/test')
    
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    server = await loop.create_server(
        lambda: EchoServerProtocol(),
        '127.0.0.1', 8544, backlog=65000)
    
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use more defined server protocols like MQTT which is widely used for sensor data?

Comment: There isn't any specific reason not to use MQTT. But before making the sensor device mentioned above, i made a similar device which communicated over TCP. I want to use my old embedded code for new sensor device mentioned above. Didn't deep dive to MQTT, but i think i will have similar scaling and async problem with even MQTT.

Comment: Well, MQTT does still work over TCP, but also Python itself isn't the ideal server language for scalability compared to Mosquito MQTT server, written in C/C++. MQTT is used in large factories with thousands of sensors. It can scale fine. But also, no, you shouldn't use a server with only one core if you want to handle several hundred socket connections. You also shouldn't use only one server if you want to guarantee 24/7 uptime

Comment: I will deep dive into MQTT and will try to understand. And yes i agreed about should work with several servers for 7/24 uptime. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: So sir, i looked a little bit into MQTT. You are basically saying that i should use a MQTT server and connect all my devices to the server. And than i should write a program which is listening the MQTT server. After every incoming data i should write to database with the help of  thread method or async method. I think this approach is better than mine. Did i get this right?

Comment: Correct. Producers (devices) send data to the server, then you have another process subscribe to the topic(s) and write to the database. The server will act as a durable buffer